# How can i create a VIEW using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create a view using psycopg2 using the following codeblock:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='abc' host='abc' user='abc' password='abc'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT 'Hello World'")
cur.close()
```

This code executes without any errors, but when i list out the views in the database the 'testview' is not listed among them.
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You should issue a commit command. conn.commit() otherwise your request is rolled back

Comment: @Mokadillion the `CREATE VIEW` doesn't need `commit`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. @Mokadillion

Comment: Actually adding commit saved the view. @BearBrown

Comment: @BearBrown I can't say i fully understand psycopg2, but using I have learned that actions are not 'commited' if the connection isn't commited itself even if the sql commands themselves do not require commit.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the schema name to the view name.
Eg: CREATE VIEW schema_name.testview AS SELECT 'Hello World'